# Regarding AWS Tools for PowerShell - Creating Workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli, amazon-workspaces

I hope life is going well. I'm in the process of trying to create AWS Workspaces for user accounts via PowerShell. I'm already familiar with the process of executing this via AWS CLI and have great success using the JSON template. However I'm running into a wall when it comes to executing this in PowerShell. My overall objective is to make the process of creating WorkSpaces a little more programmable. The current line:

```
New-WKSWorkspace -Workspace @{"BundleId" = "xxxxxx"; "UserName" = "xxxxxx"; "DirectoryId" = "xxxxxxx";}
```

This line executes just fine and creates the workspace based on the parameters entered. My issue is that I need to have the "VolumeEncryptionKey" set in the initial phase when creating the workspace. However when reading through the AWS Tools documentation for PowerShell and running this command:

```
Get-Command Get-WKSWorkspace -ShowCommandInfo
```

I'm not able to find an argument for "VolumeEncryptionKey" which is causing a problem. I thought I could set the value via:

```
(Get-WKSWorkspace -WorkspaceId xxxxxxxxxx).VolumeEncryptionKey
```

But that doesn't really help and there appears to be no "Set-WKSWorkspace" command either. Has anyone had any experience building Workspaces using the AWS Tools for PowerShell before? Please let me know.

So I tried executing that particularly command before:

```
New-WKSWorkspace -Workspace @{ "VolumeEncryptionKey" = "xxxxxx"; "BundleId" = "xxxxxx"; "UserName" = "xxxxxx"; "DirectoryId" = "xxxxxxx";}
```

But it generates an error:

[image]

[image]

Here's the JSON Skeleton that I use that works really well:

```
{
"Workspaces": [
  {
    "DirectoryId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "UserName": "xxxxxxxx",
    "BundleId": "xxxxxxxx",
    "VolumeEncryptionKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "UserVolumeEncryptionEnabled": true,
    "RootVolumeEncryptionEnabled": true,
    "WorkspaceProperties": {
      "RunningMode": "ALWAYS_ON",
      "RootVolumeSizeGib": 175,
      "UserVolumeSizeGib": 100,
      "ComputeTypeName": "PERFORMANCE"
    },
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Key": "xxxxxxx",
        "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

The game plan was to try and run this via AWS Tools for PowerShell.

Comment: That error message sounds like you're not supplying the correct `VolumeEncryptionKey` (or supplying one in an invalid format)

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory reading of [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=WorkSpaces/TWorkSpacesWorkspaceRequest.html&tocid=Amazon_WorkSpaces_Model_WorkspaceRequest) I would conclude you need to include it in the `-Workspace` argument:

```bsh
New-WKSWorkspace -Workspace @{"VolumeEncryptionKey" = "<VEK goes here>"; "BundleId" = "xxxxxx"; "UserName" = "xxxxxx"; "DirectoryId" = "xxxxxxx"; }
```

Comment: I gave that a shot before. But the command doesn't execute properly in PowerShell. It outputs the error: "The security token included in the request is invalid".

Comment: @ahahmed3293 What does "doesn't execute properly" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say? I can't see your screen :)

Comment: Hi Mathias, I tried updating the initial post. I'm a little new to Stack OverFlow so I added the snapshots above.